# How could I write a program which accepts character input then checks the characters against a list of words they could form?

Tags: r, for-loop, search

I'm trying (struggling) to write a program which takes character input from the user, then checks a list of preset words for which word could be formed from the given characters. It asks for 5 separate characters, creates a list from these characters, and repeats this 5 times for a total of 25 characters. This is meant to represent the functions of a combination lock which has 5 separate dials, each of which containing 5 letters.

Asking for input and defining some lists:
`

```
letters <- list()
possible <- list()


for (i in 1:5){
    var1 = as.character(readline(prompt = 'First Letter: '))
    var2 = as.character(readline(prompt = 'Second Letter: '))
    var3 = as.character(readline(prompt = 'Third Letter: '))
    var4 = as.character(readline(prompt = 'Fourth Letter: '))
    var5 = as.character(readline(prompt = 'Fifth Letter: '))
    tmp <- list(var1, var2, var3, var4, var5)
    letters <- tmp
}
```

`

`key <- list(some 5 letter words)`

With this program, the order of the characters would matter. For example, if the first set of inputs was (a, r, v, s, t), I would only want to check if the first letter of each word was one of these. Now I've only been using R (and coding in general) for about a week, so I apologize if my attempt at creating this program is offensive to those more experienced:

`

```
for (j in keys){
  for (i in letters){
    for (k in 1:5){
      if (letters[[i]][k] %in% substr(keys[[j]], 1, 1){
        possible <- rep(keys[[j]]
         {
          
        }
      }
    
    }
    
}
```

`

I hit a bit of a wall here and can't figure out how to continue. I'm certain there are more efficient ways to do this but I'm completely stuck.

***While this program is modeled around a combination lock, I do not intend to use it to solve actual combination locks. This is solely a thought experiment so I can get some practice with coding.***

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for. I have a lot of style feedback (use a vector, not sequentially named variables, don't use a `list` unless you need to, use more descriptive object names, etc.). But the Code Review stack exchange is a better place for feedback like that. I don't know what your intended next step is, so I don't know how to help you get unstuck following your method. You don't have share a sample of `keys` so we can't really run and test your code.

Comment: Generally, I think regex would work well here and simplify the problem a lot. You could make a regex pattern of `[first letters][second letters]...[fifth letters]` and use `grep` on the keys. It wouldn't teach you how to use for loops because you wouldn't need any (except for maybe the input), but I do think it would solve your problem.

Comment: well, perhaps, for a full word, `the_word <- suppressMessages(strsplit(readline(prompt('type a word')), '')[[1]])
type a word.Rd`, and user types something, and that is in 'the_word' as separate letters. And doesn't care how long word is.

Comment: If you'd like to see an alternate solution, it would help to make an example reproducible. Give a few (less than 10!) examples words to look for(can't tell if you're calling these `keys` or `possible`), and a sample user input, and then desired result for that input. Maybe simplify down to 3 letter words to make it an easy example.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working solution for my understanding of your problem:

```
find_possible_words = function(dictionary, n_dials) {
  dials = character(n_dials)
  for(i in 1:n_dials) {
    dials[i] = readline(prompt = paste0("Please input the letters on dial #", i, " "))
  }
  regex_pattern = paste("[", dials, "]", sep = "", collapse = "")
  grep(pattern = regex_pattern, x = dictionary, ignore.case = TRUE, value = TRUE)
}

find_possible_words(dictionary = c("cat", "dog", "rat", "try"), n_dials = 3)

# Please input the letters on dial #1 abcd
# Please input the letters on dial #2 aor
# Please input the letters on dial #3 tgb
# [1] "cat" "dog"
```

The main idea is to use regex to search the dictionary. A regex pattern of `[xyz]` matches any one of "x", "y", "z", and a pattern of `[xyz][abc]` will match x or y or z, followed by a or b or c, and so forth. So we wrap the choices for each letter in square brackets and stick them together, and then use `grep` to find words in the dictionary that match the pattern.